# Flask app not running

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Index!"

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return "Members"



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am trying to run the above example program, I am not sure how to check the output in browser.
I tried the links - http://127.0.0.1:5000/hello , http://127.0.0.1:5000/members nothing come up.
Help me if I am missing anything ?

Comment: This code works fine

Comment: Is Flask installed on your system?..and how are u running your app?..Please, edit your question with more details.

Comment: It could be that you need to include port or/and host

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Flask is installed in your system you can try something like `$ pip freeze | grep flask`,  if not run

```
$ pip install Flask
```

And when you run your app like `$ python <filename>.py` you see something like

```
* Running on http://localhost:5000/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Flask follow these steps and you will be able to view the paths on a browser. First install virtualenv & pip.

```
sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Create a directory wher you will store your object.

```
mkdir yourflaskapp
cd yourflaskapp
```

Create your virtual environment where you will install flask.

```
virtualenv yourvirtualenv
```

After succesfully creating your virtual environment, activate it using the following command. To deactivate type and run `deactivate`.

```
source yourvirtualenv/bin/activate
```

Now install flask in your virtual environment.

```
pip install flask
```

Create file app.py below then run `python app.py`.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Index!"

@app.route("/hello")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/members")
def members():
    return "Members"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```